# filter out text javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="edit-mode-panel">


    <div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="border:medium black solid; background:yellow; color:black; margin:20px; padding:10px;">
    <div id="test2" data-name="Page Field: Jump Link Choice"><div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Jump Link Choice</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"><span dir="none"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Heading 1"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl02$ctl00$ctl00" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00">Heading 1</label></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Heading 2"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl01" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl02$ctl00$ctl01" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl01">Heading 2</label></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Heading 3"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl02" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl02$ctl00$ctl02" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl02">Heading 3</label></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Heading 4"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl03" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl02$ctl00$ctl03" /><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl03">Heading 4</label></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table></span></div></div>
    </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

I have this bit of code, how can I filter out so it just says

```
    <tr>
        <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Heading 1"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl02$ctl00$ctl00" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00">Heading 1</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Heading 2"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl01" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl02$ctl00$ctl01" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl01">Heading 2</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Heading 3"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl02" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl02$ctl00$ctl02" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl02">Heading 3</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Heading 4"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl03" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl02$ctl00$ctl03" /><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl03">Heading 4</label></span></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: wrong stackoverflow sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to get the inner content.

var innerContent = $("div.edit-mode-panel").find('table:first').html();

$("#result").append(innerContent);